# Camera streaming service works only with localhost but not with IP address

Tags: angularjs, camera, ip-camera, mendix

I have implemented a service which streams camera output on html5. But it works only if I use **localhost**:8080 localhost if I use IP address or machine name then it does not even detect the camera.

```js
/*global logger*/
/*
    VisualInspection
    ========================

    @file      : VisualInspection.js
    @version   : 1.0.0
    @author    : 
    @date      : 7/28/2019
    @copyright : 
    @license   : Apache 2

    Documentation
    ========================
    Describe your widget here.
*/

// Required module list. Remove unnecessary modules, you can always get them back from the boilerplate.
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "mxui/widget/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",

    "mxui/dom",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/dom-prop",
    "dojo/dom-geometry",
    "dojo/dom-class",
    "dojo/dom-style",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/text",
    "dojo/html",
    "dojo/_base/event",
    "VisualInspection/lib/jquery-1.11.2",
    "dojo/text!VisualInspection/widget/template/VisualInspection.html",
    "VisualInspection/widget/template/tf.min",
    // "dojo/text!VisualInspection/widget/template/labels.json",
    // "dojo/text!VisualInspection/widget/template/model.json"

], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, dom, dojoDom, dojoProp, dojoGeometry, dojoClass, dojoStyle, dojoConstruct, dojoArray, lang, dojoText, dojoHtml, dojoEvent, _jQuery, widgetTemplate, tf) {
    "use strict";


    var $ = _jQuery.noConflict(true);
    var LABELS_URL = "http://pni6w2465:7777/EasyPlan/model_web/labels.json"
    var MODEL_JSON = "http://pni6w2465:7777/EasyPlan/model_web/model.json"

    // var tf = require(['../../VisualInspection/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs']);

    //////////////
    const TFWrapper = model => {
        const calculateMaxScores = (scores, numBoxes, numClasses) => {
            const maxes = []
            const classes = []
            for (let i = 0; i < numBoxes; i++) {
                let max = Number.MIN_VALUE
                let index = -1
                for (let j = 0; j < numClasses; j++) {
                    if (scores[i * numClasses + j] > max) {
                        max = scores[i * numClasses + j]
                        index = j
                    }
                }
                maxes[i] = max
                classes[i] = index
            }
            return [maxes, classes]
        }

        const buildDetectedObjects = (
            width,
            height,
            boxes,
            scores,
            indexes,
            classes
        ) => {
            const count = indexes.length
            const objects = []
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                const bbox = []
                for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    bbox[j] = boxes[indexes[i] * 4 + j]
                }
                const minY = bbox[0] * height
                const minX = bbox[1] * width
                const maxY = bbox[2] * height
                const maxX = bbox[3] * width
                bbox[0] = minX
                bbox[1] = minY
                bbox[2] = maxX - minX
                bbox[3] = maxY - minY
                objects.push({
                    bbox: bbox,
                    class: classes[indexes[i]],
                    score: scores[indexes[i]]
                })
            }
            return objects
        }
        var img = null;
        const detect = input => {
            const batched = tf.tidy(() => {
                const img = tf.browser.fromPixels(input)
                
                // Reshape to a single-element batch so we can pass it to executeAsync.
                // var img = null;
                // //sid
                // var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvasElement");
                // if (canvas.getContext) {
                //     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                //     img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    
                // }

                
                return img.expandDims(0)
                
            })

            const height = batched.shape[1]
            const width = batched.shape[2]

            // const height = img.height
            // const width = img.width

            return model.executeAsync(batched).then(result => {
                const scores = result[0].dataSync()
                const boxes = result[1].dataSync()

                // clean the webgl tensors
                batched.dispose()
                tf.dispose(result)

                const [maxScores, classes] = calculateMaxScores(
                    scores,
                    result[0].shape[1],
                    result[0].shape[2]
                )

                const prevBackend = tf.getBackend()
                // run post process in cpu
                tf.setBackend('cpu')
                const indexTensor = tf.tidy(() => {
                    const boxes2 = tf.tensor2d(boxes, [
                        result[1].shape[1],
                        result[1].shape[3]
                    ])
                    return tf.image.nonMaxSuppression(
                        boxes2,
                        maxScores,
                        20, // maxNumBoxes
                        0.5, // iou_threshold
                        0.5 // score_threshold
                    )
                })
                const indexes = indexTensor.dataSync()
                indexTensor.dispose()
                // restore previous backend
                tf.setBackend(prevBackend)

                return buildDetectedObjects(
                    width,
                    height,
                    boxes,
                    maxScores,
                    indexes,
                    classes
                )
            })
        }
        return {
            detect: detect
        }
    }







    //////////////////////


    // Declare widget's prototype.
    return declare("VisualInspection.widget.VisualInspection", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        // _TemplatedMixin will create our dom node using this HTML template.
        templateString: widgetTemplate,

        // DOM elements
        inputNodes: null,
        colorSelectNode: null,
        colorInputNode: null,
        infoTextNode: null,

        // Parameters configured in the Modeler.
        mfToExecute: "",
        messageString: "",
        backgroundColor: "",

        // Internal variables. Non-primitives created in the prototype are shared between all widget instances.
        _handles: null,
        _contextObj: null,
        _alertDiv: null,
        _readOnly: false,

        // dojo.declare.constructor is called to construct the widget instance. Implement to initialize non-primitive properties.
        constructor: function () {
            logger.debug(this.id + ".constructor");
            this._handles = [];
        },


        // dijit._WidgetBase.postCreate is called after constructing the widget. Implement to do extra setup work.
        postCreate: function () {
            logger.debug(this.id + ".postCreate");

            if (this.readOnly || this.get("disabled") || this.readonly) {
                this._readOnly = true;
            }

            this._updateRendering();
            this._setupEvents();

            var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
            var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvasElement");

            // if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            // navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
            //     .then(function (stream) {
            //     video.srcObject = stream;
            //     })
            //     .catch(function (err0r) {
            //     console.log("Something went wrong!");
            //     });
            // }

            

    
               
                

            this.componentDidMount();
        },



        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        componentDidMount: function () {

            var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

            if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                const webCamPromise = navigator.mediaDevices
                    .getUserMedia({
                        audio: false,
                        video: {
                            facingMode: 'user'
                        }
                    })
                    .then(stream => {
                        window.stream = stream
                        video.srcObject = stream
                        return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
                            video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                                resolve()
                            }
                        })
                    })

                const modelPromise = tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_JSON)
                const labelsPromise = fetch(LABELS_URL).then(data => data.json())
                Promise.all([modelPromise, labelsPromise, webCamPromise])
                    .then(values => {
                        const [model, labels] = values
                        this.detectFrame(video, model, labels)
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(error)
                    })
            }
        },

        detectFrame: function (video, model, labels) {
            TFWrapper(model)
                .detect(video)
                .then(predictions => {
                    this.renderPredictions(predictions, labels)
                    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                        this.detectFrame(video, model, labels)
                    })
                })
        },

        renderPredictions: function (predictions, labels) {
            var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvasElement");
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
            // Font options.
            const font = '16px sans-serif'
            ctx.font = font
            ctx.textBaseline = 'top'
            predictions.forEach(prediction => {
                const x = prediction.bbox[0]
                const y = prediction.bbox[1]
                const width = prediction.bbox[2]
                const height = prediction.bbox[3]
                const label = labels[parseInt(prediction.class)]
                // Draw the bounding box.
                ctx.strokeStyle = '#00FFFF'
                ctx.lineWidth = 4
                ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height)
                // Draw the label background.
                ctx.fillStyle = '#00FFFF'
                const textWidth = ctx.measureText(label).width
                const textHeight = parseInt(font, 10) // base 10
                ctx.fillRect(x, y, textWidth + 4, textHeight + 4)
            })

            predictions.forEach(prediction => {
                const x = prediction.bbox[0]
                const y = prediction.bbox[1]
                const label = labels[parseInt(prediction.class)]
                // Draw the text last to ensure it's on top.
                ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'
                ctx.fillText(label, x, y)
            })
        },


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // mxui.widget._WidgetBase.update is called when context is changed or initialized. Implement to re-render and / or fetch data.
        update: function (obj, callback) {
            logger.debug(this.id + ".update");

            this._contextObj = obj;
            this._resetSubscriptions();
            this._updateRendering(callback); // We're passing the callback to updateRendering to be called after DOM-manipulation
        },

        // mxui.widget._WidgetBase.enable is called when the widget should enable editing. Implement to enable editing if widget is input widget.
        enable: function () {
            logger.debug(this.id + ".enable");
        },

        // mxui.widget._WidgetBase.enable is called when the widget should disable editing. Implement to disable editing if widget is input widget.
        disable: function () {
            logger.debug(this.id + ".disable");
        },

        // mxui.widget._WidgetBase.resize is called when the page's layout is recalculated. Implement to do sizing calculations. Prefer using CSS instead.
        resize: function (box) {
            logger.debug(this.id + ".resize");
        },

        // mxui.widget._WidgetBase.uninitialize is called when the widget is destroyed. Implement to do special tear-down work.
        uninitialize: function () {
            logger.debug(this.id + ".uninitialize");
            // Clean up listeners, helper objects, etc. There is no need to remove listeners added with this.connect / this.subscribe / this.own.
        },

        // We want to stop events on a mobile device
        _stopBubblingEventOnMobile: function (e) {
            logger.debug(this.id + "._stopBubblingEventOnMobile");
            if (typeof document.ontouchstart !== "undefined") {
                dojoEvent.stop(e);
            }
        },

        // Attach events to HTML dom elements
        _setupEvents: function () {
            logger.debug(this.id + "._setupEvents");
            this.connect(this.colorSelectNode, "change", function (e) {
                // Function from mendix object to set an attribute.
                this._contextObj.set(this.backgroundColor, this.colorSelectNode.value);
            });

            this.connect(this.infoTextNode, "click", function (e) {
                // Only on mobile stop event bubbling!
                this._stopBubblingEventOnMobile(e);

                // If a microflow has been set execute the microflow on a click.
                if (this.mfToExecute !== "") {
                    this._execMf(this.mfToExecute, this._contextObj.getGuid());
                }
            });
        },

        _execMf: function (mf, guid, cb) {
            logger.debug(this.id + "._execMf");
            if (mf && guid) {
                mx.ui.action(mf, {
                    params: {
                        applyto: "selection",
                        guids: [guid]
                    },
                    callback: lang.hitch(this, function (objs) {
                        if (cb && typeof cb === "function") {
                            cb(objs);
                        }
                    }),
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.debug(error.description);
                    }
                }, this);
            }
        },

        // Rerender the interface.
        _updateRendering: function (callback) {
            logger.debug(this.id + "._updateRendering");


            // Important to clear all validations!
            this._clearValidations();

            // The callback, coming from update, needs to be executed, to let the page know it finished rendering
            this._executeCallback(callback, "_updateRendering");
        },

        // Handle validations.
        _handleValidation: function (validations) {
            logger.debug(this.id + "._handleValidation");
            this._clearValidations();

            var validation = validations[0],
                message = validation.getReasonByAttribute(this.backgroundColor);

            if (this._readOnly) {
                validation.removeAttribute(this.backgroundColor);
            } else if (message) {
                this._addValidation(message);
                validation.removeAttribute(this.backgroundColor);
            }
        },

        // Clear validations.
        _clearValidations: function () {
            logger.debug(this.id + "._clearValidations");
            dojoConstruct.destroy(this._alertDiv);
            this._alertDiv = null;
        },

        // Show an error message.
        _showError: function (message) {
            logger.debug(this.id + "._showError");
            if (this._alertDiv !== null) {
                dojoHtml.set(this._alertDiv, message);
                return true;
            }
            this._alertDiv = dojoConstruct.create("div", {
                "class": "alert alert-danger",
                "innerHTML": message
            });
            dojoConstruct.place(this._alertDiv, this.domNode);
        },

        // Add a validation.
        _addValidation: function (message) {
            logger.debug(this.id + "._addValidation");
            this._showError(message);
        },

        // Reset subscriptions.
        _resetSubscriptions: function () {
            logger.debug(this.id + "._resetSubscriptions");
            // Release handles on previous object, if any.
            this.unsubscribeAll();

            // When a mendix object exists create subscribtions.
            if (this._contextObj) {
                this.subscribe({
                    guid: this._contextObj.getGuid(),
                    callback: lang.hitch(this, function (guid) {
                        this._updateRendering();
                    })
                });

                this.subscribe({
                    guid: this._contextObj.getGuid(),
                    attr: this.backgroundColor,
                    callback: lang.hitch(this, function (guid, attr, attrValue) {
                        this._updateRendering();
                    })
                });

                this.subscribe({
                    guid: this._contextObj.getGuid(),
                    val: true,
                    callback: lang.hitch(this, this._handleValidation)
                });
            }
        },

        _executeCallback: function (cb, from) {
            logger.debug(this.id + "._executeCallback" + (from ? " from " + from : ""));
            if (cb && typeof cb === "function") {
                cb();
            }
        }
    });
});

require(["VisualInspection/widget/VisualInspection"]);
```

```html
<div id="container">
            <video autoplay="true" playsInline="true" width="600" height="500"  id="videoElement" style="position: fixed;" >
            </video>
            <canvas  id= "canvasElement" width="600" height="500" style="position: absolute;">
                </canvas>
            
        </div>
```

From Above code, When I run using localhost this code will execute :

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

When I run using machine name or IP name : 
This code is not considered in developer tool of chrome  due to security or some reason

Comment: please share the code you tried

Comment: @jazib updated code snippet

Comment: @PrasadSDeshpande - did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into the same thing.